# mysql total and difference for multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to mysql. I'm trying to write a query to calculate the total and difference for multiple rows, and then put them in specific columns.

Eg. I want to sum all Entity'A' of Type'1' then subtract from the result, the sum of Entity'A' of type'0'. While simultaneously populating a table to show where this difference is positive or negative.

Sample table:

```
Entity Type   Value
A      1      200
B      1      500
C      0      350
B      0      150
C      1      100
A      1      50
A      1      350
```

Expected Output:

```
Entity    Diff-Positive    Diff-Negative
A         600
B         350
C                          250
```

Note that Entity'A' for example may not have an entry for Type'0'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically aggregation.  You need a conditional to split the values into separate columns.  One way uses `greatest()`:

```
select entity,
       greatest(sum(case when type = 1 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_positive,
       greatest(sum(case when type = 0 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_positive    
from t
group by entity;
```

Comment: Thanks alot your solution works like magic. For the purpose of comparison and learning though. please oblige me with any other ways you know same result can be achieved.

Comment: Also if i were to require all Diff-Positive to come before Diff-Negative in my result set, while sill paying attention to the order of 'Entity'. i.e if Entity'A' and are Entity'B' are Diff-Negatives, Entity'B' can not come before Entity'A' in the result set because of alphabetic order etc. How can this be done?

Comment: @Ken . . . I think you should ask another question with more details.